# clickatell sms "Recipient phone number is invalid or recipient does not want to receive SMS"

Tags: sms, clickatell

wordpress 4.9.6 Clickatell 4.1
All was working fine until upgrade to Civi 5.22 and upgrade to SMS API 1.5
(yup in retrospect should have tested separately!)

phone is home-mobile-primary

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Activity/BAO/Activity.php` is failing in function `function sendSMSMessage(` because `$doNotSms = TRUE;` on line 3154. Set it to false and you should be Ok. However, the check will not happen, so all numbers (even Do Not SMS #s) will get the SMS.

The other option is to comment out the following block and add an if block: 
`/*
    if ($smsProviderParams['To']) {
      // If phone number is specified use it
      $toPhoneNumber = trim($smsProviderParams['To']);
      Civi::log()->debug(print_r($smsProviderParams, true)."\ntoID: $toID\n");
      //echo "<pre>".print_r($smsProviderParams, true)."</pre>";
      $doNotSms = FALSE;
    }
    elseif ($toID) {
*/
    if ($toID) {
      // No phone number specified, so find a suitable one for the contact`

Comment: Brilliant - option 1 worked a treat.  Thanks so much! FYI in wordpress it's line 1820

Answer (score 1):

Have raised this as an issue with the extension maintainers:

https://github.com/veda-consulting/org.civicrm.sms.clickatell/issues/20

Comment: It's a Civi core bug, see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/273 .

Answer (score 0):

This is a Civi core bug. It happens with Twilio too: I tested in Civi 5.4.0 .

Seamus Lee has filed an [issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/273) against Civi core and submitted a [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/a9b7ee41eeae0a75d0c8bfc62caa81edf3024b83).